# Stripping html tags using php

Tags: php, strip-tags

How can i strip html tag except the content inside the pre tag

code

```
$content="
    <div id="wrapper">

    Notes


    </div>


    <pre>
    <div id="loginfos">asdasd</div>

    </pre>
";
```

While using strip_tags($content,'')  the html inside the pre tag too stripped of. but i don't want the html inside pre stripped off

Comment: can you check for the updated answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following:

1. Use preg_replace with 'e' modifier to replace contents of pre tags with some strings like @@@1@@@, @@@2@@@, etc. while storing this contents in some array
2. Run strip_tags()
3. Run preg_relace with 'e' modifier again to restore @@@1@@@, etc. into original contents.

A bit kludgy but should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
echo strip_tags($text, '<pre>');
```

Comment: is well Ya i tried that with pre instead of pre but no result..My Question to strip_tags($content,'<pre>')had it ..but stackoverflow stipred my pre tag on question

Comment: i tried that .. but the problem is the html inside pre is also striped of check

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php 
                    $document=html_entity_decode($content);
                    $search = array ("'<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>'si","'<[/!]*?[^<>]*?>'si","'([rn])[s]+'","'&(quot|#34);'i","'&(amp|#38);'i","'&(lt|#60);'i","'&(gt|#62);'i","'&(nbsp|#160);'i","'&(iexcl|#161);'i","'&(cent|#162);'i","'&(pound|#163);'i","'&(copy|#169);'i","'&#(d+);'e");
                    $replace = array ("","","\1","\"","&","<",">"," ",chr(161),chr(162),chr(163),chr(169),"chr(\1)");
                    $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $document); 
                    echo $text;
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'YOUR CODE HERE';

$org_text = $text;

// hide content within pre tags
$text = preg_replace( '/(<pre[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/pre>)/is', '$1@@@pre@@@$3', $text );
// filter content
$text = strip_tags( $text, '<pre>' );
// insert back content of pre tags
if ( preg_match_all( '/(<pre[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/pre>)/is', $org_text, $parts ) ) {
    foreach ( $parts[2] as $code ) {
        $text = preg_replace( '/@@@pre@@@/', $code, $text, 1 );
    }
}

print_r( $text );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok!, you leave nothing but one choice: Regular Expressions... Nobody likes 'em, but they sure get the job done. First, replace the problematic text with something weird, like this:

```
preg_replace("#<pre>(.+?)</pre>#", "||k||", $content);
```

This will effectively change your

```
<pre> blah, blah, bllah....</pre>
```

for something else, and then call

```
strip_tags($content);
```

After that, you can just replace the original value in ||k||(or whatever you choose) and you'll get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think your content is not stored very well in the $content variable

could you check once by converting inner double quotes to single quotes

```
$content="
    <div id='wrapper'>

    Notes


    </div>


    <pre>
    <div id='loginfos'>asdasd</div>

    </pre>
";


strip_tags($content, '<pre>');
```

Comment: I don't think that what was meant - this code would leave pre tag intact, but will still strip the tags inside the pre tag.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

Use preg_replace with `'e'` modifier to replace contents of pre tags with some strings like `@@@1@@@`, `@@@2@@@`, etc. while storing this contents in some array
Run `strip_tags()`

Run preg_relace with `'e'` modifier again to restore `@@@1@@@`, etc. into original contents.

A bit kludgy but should work.

**Could you please write full code. I understood, but something goes wrong. Please write full programming code**